# (Nodejs Nock) Is there a cleaner way to simulate a response that changes with time in Nock

Tags: node.js, nock

I know that nock allows for queueing mocks for the same endpoint like I have here:

```
nock('https://example.test')
.get('/')
.delayConnection(400)
.reply(200, MockApiResponses.proccessing) //response on first get
.get('/')
.delayConnection(150)
.reply(200, MockApiResponses.goodRetrieve) //response on second
```

I wish to simulate a scenrio where my first reply is being sent for the first 5-20 min, and then the last one after. However, I don't want to chain 100 of these gets, delays, and replies.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple different options.

First, if your delays are consistent for the first N number of requests, you can use the [`.times()`](https://github.com/nock/nock#repeat-response-n-times) method to specify a large number for your first request.

If that doesn't work for your case, you can always use a dynamic response function and write your own logic on which response body to return.
[Docs for specifying responses.](https://github.com/nock/nock#specifying-replies)

```
nock('https://example.test')
  .get('/')
  .reply(200, () => {
    if (someLogic()) return MockApiResponses.proccessing;
    return MockApiResponses.goodRetrieve;
  })
```